# Implementing a DEX with Substrate on the Polkadot Network, Allowing Custom Token Creation and Addition

Tags: substrate-node-template, smart-contract, pallet-dex

I am in the process of developing a decentralized exchange (DEX) using Substrate on the Polkadot network and could use some assistance with the implementation. The key features I want to incorporate into my DEX are as follows:

1. Enable users to create their own tokens with the Substrate contract
   node, utilizing ink!.
2. Allow users to deploy the created token    contracts on my network
   using substrate-node-contract.
3. Permit users    to list their custom tokens on the DEX for trading.

My question is related to the interaction between the token contracts and the DEX. When users deploy their token contracts on the network with substrate-node-contract, will I be able to use the smart contract address for transferring tokens within the DEX?

I would appreciate any guidance on implementing these features in a Substrate pallet, as well as suggestions or resources that could be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe this question's scope is too large? Need more focus? --- (ask chatgpt LOL, no offences, just kidding)

Comment: @AurevoirXavier i dont know . i need some clue to strat the implement dex by this option ( allow user to upload smart contract on my network and use the smart contract for transfer token to other users )

Comment: @AurevoirXavier , i asked , it could not answer me , it have updated from 2021

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are asking is whether it is possible for smart contract to interact with the `pallet-assets`? The answer is yes. You can do so in the low-level way using [chain-extensions](https://use.ink/macros-attributes/chain-extension) or referring to [OpenBrush example](https://docs.openbrush.io/smart-contracts/PSP22-Pallet/) on how to interact and create new PSP22 tokens from the ink! smart contract.

Realistically, I would advise to start with proof-of-concept of the DEX in ink! before moving onto FRAME development.

You can use [Uniswap V2](https://github.com/swanky-dapps/dex) implementation in ink! by Astar for inspiration.

Comment: why i have to use proof-of-concept ?

Comment: You don't have to use it, I recommend you to develop DEX in ink! first before doing in in FRAME.

Comment: i want implement DEx in substrate pallet , not in the ink! . i want allow user created their token with ink! and deploy that on my chain , also they can add their token into my dex .

Comment: You runtime should have `pallet-assets` to allow token creation and `pallet-contracts` for smart contract functionality. The users can create their tokens in ink! by interacting with the `pallet-assets` through chain extensions as illustrated in the example by OpenBrush.

Comment: i have to use `pallet-assets` ? can i call `pallet-contracts` functions without use `pallet-assets` ?

Comment: You call `pallet-assets` functions from your smart contract, not vice-versa. `pallet-assets` is ready-to-use pallet to create tokens. Smart Contracts live in sandboxed and untrusted environment. You either need to expose your DEX functions to smart contracts through chain-extensions or build it as a smart contract.

Comment: i think we have misunderstanding here . i don't want create index with smart contract . i want to create dex in runtime . users want to create thier token with smart contract .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144953/discussion-between-german-nikolishin-and-mr-coder).